# Bootstrap toggle on DataTables works but breaks on paginated pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Im using bootstrap toggle and have a toggle all button. The button will toggle everything in the current paginated page. But will not toggle the items on the other pages. How do I get it to toggle every individual row in the table? This is the JS i'm currently using.

```
table.on('draw', function() {
  $('.js-bs-toggle').bootstrapToggle({
    on: 'Yes',
    off: 'No'
  });
});

$('.js-toggle-all').on('click', function() {
  $('.js-bs-toggle').bootstrapToggle('toggle');
})
```

Comment: Is there a way to iterate thru each row using something like table.rows().data(); and then trigger a toggle or use addClass to toggle on ?

Comment: As seen in the list if dupe examples, use either `draw.dt` (all events have a `.dt` namespace) or `drawCallback()`.